# Height in percentage does not apply

Tags: html, css, percentage

I'd like to understand why in my case, the *height: x%* does not apply. With percentage the div/section always get *height:0*.

```
My code:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aHhmD
```

Comment: Please post your code: putting the link to your code into a code block doesn't make it code.

Comment: Ctrl+C , Ctrl+V. Try to put it as a link and see if the system let you do that =)

Comment: The system doesn't allow you to post *only* the link because you should include the relevant parts of your code in the question.

Comment: If it is all in the codepen, why should I ? It makes all clean and the  codepen there is only the necesssary code...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253459/links-to-jsfiddle-net-must-be-accompanied-by-code-should-tell-the-user-exactl

Comment: Don't be lazy, if you ask for help, then please, give us your code right here.

Comment: @Aleksandar Don't be such a bad person !! You have no obligation to answer any question. Other people already answered it nicely and polite. Next time, try to be less stupid, if you can't, just skip the question. The community thanks you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an element to have a height in percentage applied, its ancestors must have a height applied.  Your section.geral only has a min-height applied.  Give it a height instead:

```
html, body{ 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  height:100%
}

.geral{
  position: relative;
  display: block;       
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #008000;
}

.um{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: navy;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

.dois{
    position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `width` and `height` instead of `min-width` and `min-height` also fixes the issue.

Comment: Could you explain to me, why it works without the 'min' ? I used min because I was afraid to screw the bootstrap's responsive.